# Offset scroll is janky

Tags: jquery

A plugin on my site dynamically adds an onclick event to all the items in a list. When the user click a list item, the page scrolls to the desired element. I would like to add some offset to the scroll position without editing the plugin code.

Plugin code:

```
event.preventDefault();
var page = jQuery(elm).attr('href');
var speed = 750;
jQuery('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: jQuery(page).offset().top + 2 }, speed );
jQuery(page).focus();
return false;
```

I've added my own click function that does it's own scrolling. It scrolls to the plugin offset and then readjusts to my scroll position. So it scrolls to 0, for example and then down to 20.

Can the code be adjusted so the scroll just goes to 20? I've adjusted the speed to 0 but that causes the scroll to flicker.

```
$('.nav li').live('click', function () {
        var targetCategory = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(targetCategory).offset().top - (offerHeight + headerHeight) + 'px'
        }, 150);
    }
});
```

Comment: It will be difficult to answer without knowing what the plugin is or how it is scrolling the page. You'll likely need to change the plugin settings, config, or parameters (or modify the plugin) in order to get the effect you desire.

Comment: I updated my question and added the plugin code. There's no option to change or config the plugin.

Comment: Then you should remove the plugin and only use a custom solution. The plugin code seems simple enough to be able to replicate and modify.

Comment: Thanks Sean, the code I posted from the plugin is only a small snippet which I am trying to modify. The actual plugin is a POS system for a restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice where your code is fighting each other. You should definitely find a way to edit the plugin, or remove it.

If that is absolutely not an option, try removing the event handlers for your element before adding your own code (which can be a modified version of your plugin.)

Use the `off()` method to remove event handlers. [doc](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

I'm not sure which element your plugin is attached to, but if it's '.nav li', then run `$('.nav li').off()`

Also, `.live()` is deprecated. Use `.on()` instead. [doc](https://api.jquery.com/live/)

Note: It jitters because of your "animations" are running at the same time, but at each frame, the scrollTop is set to the value from the animation, then instantly the second animation.

Comment: The plugin can't be removed and if I edit it then i'll lose the edits if/when it's updated. I'll have to settle for my workaround for now. Thanks for the .on() update.